# Want to get Session Variable in other page but its not showing up. What can I do?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, authentication, session-variables

I have added this lines of codes in my functions.php file

```
 public function login(){
    $sql = "SELECT `ID`,`userName` FROM `userdata` WHERE `userName`=:userN AND `password`=:passd";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":userN",$this->userName);
    $stmt ->bindValue(":passd",$this->password);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $userData = $stmt ->fetch();
    $check = $stmt ->rowCount();
    if($check==1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['uid']   = $userData['ID'];
        $_SESSION['uName']   = $userData['userName'];
        $_SESSION['Name']   = $userData['Name'];
        $_SESSION['login_msg'] = "Login Successful";
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
public function getSession(){
    return @$_SESSION['login'];
}
```

And in my index.php file I want to get the Name that needs to come from mysql database.

```
    session_start();
include_once "functions.php";
$object = new functions();
$userName   = $_SESSION['uName'];
$Name       = $_SESSION['Name'];
if(!$object->getSession()){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
} 
echo "Welcome". $Name;
```

But this is not showing up index.php page. whats the problem?

Comment: instead of declaring session_start() inside the function, try putting outside of the function.

Comment: Did you check the DB return, is it successful? Passwords should be hashed. Why are you using `@` is there an error message you are ignoring that might be useful here?

Comment: DB return is successful. And I have used @ to hide a notice of undefined variable $_SESSION['login'];

Comment: after the login is successful I mean if username & password is matched then the session will start @MuthaFury .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
session_start();
public function login(){
   $sql = "SELECT `ID`,`userName` FROM `userdata` WHERE `userName`=:userN AND `password`=:passd";
   $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt -> bindValue(":userN",$this->userName);
   $stmt ->bindValue(":passd",$this->password);
   $stmt ->execute();
   $userData = $stmt ->fetch();
   $check = $stmt ->rowCount();
   if($check==1){
      $_SESSION['login'] = true;
      $_SESSION['uid']   = $userData['ID'];
      $_SESSION['uName']   = $userData['userName'];
      $_SESSION['Name']   = $userData['Name'];
      $_SESSION['login_msg'] = "Login Successful";
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

You do not even have to use a function to get the session. You can use $_SESSION['login'] anytime or anywhere you like. But make sure you have to include functions.php in all the files where you want to use the session.

Comment: I have included the functions.php file. but in the index.php file its not showing the name from the database. any problem with  $userData = $stmt ->fetch(); ? 
@spod

Comment: It was a query problem. I have fixed it by replacing SELECT `ID`,`userName` to SELECT * FROM .....